# How to find interval of convergence of series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

Each term of $x^m$ is also a term of $x^{ln(m)}$, so interval of convergence must be smaller than $(-1,1)$.
So option (a) is correct since $e>1$, but how to explicitly arrive at interval $(0,1/e)$.
please suggest.

Comment: Note that if $x=1/e$, we  have $x^{\ln m}=\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: I just need one more hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the integral test:

In order for the sum to converge, the integral of the expression must converge as well.

The integral of $x^{\ln {m}}$ with respect to $m$ is $\frac {m x^{\ln{m}}}{1+\ln{x}}$. So:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{\ln {m}} dm
= \lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \frac {s x^{\ln{s}}}{1+\ln{x}} - \frac 1 {1+\ln{x}}\\
=\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \frac {s x^{\ln{s}} -1}{1+\ln{x}}\\
=\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \frac {s^{1+ \ln{x}} -1}{1+\ln{x}}\\
=\frac {(-1)+\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}s^{1+ \ln{x}}}{1 + \ln x}
$$
In order for the above expression to converge, the value of $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} s^{1+\ln{x}}$ must converge as well. Then, the exponent of $s$ must be $0$ or negative. That is:
$$
1+ \ln x \leq 0\\
\ln x \leq -1\\
x \leq \frac 1 e
$$
Since the denominator of a fraction cannot be zero, $1 + \ln{x} \neq 0$, so $x \neq \frac 1 e$.

The number in a logarithm must be greater than zero, so $x > 0$.

Combining all information, you obtain $0 < x < \frac 1 e$.

**Edit:**

This would be easier:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{\ln m} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty m^{\ln x}
$$
This converges when $\ln x < -1$ (use the integral test or the definition of [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)), which gives you $0 < x < \frac 1 e$.